# NullpointerException during display data in a dynamically created layout

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am creating an app which should display the bus-route.
My problem is a NullpointerException during displaying the routes.
The layout is created dynamical with a Lyoutinflater.
I am getting the data from a sqlite3 database and filter it out with a cursor.
I am tryng to display this in the layout with 5 textViews.
I think there is a failure in creating the layout and or displaying the data in the TextViews.

Here is my Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{at.atn.android/at.atn.android.PlanAusgabeSubActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at at.atn.android.PlanAusgabeSubActivity.getRoute(PlanAusgabeSubActivity.java:111)
            at at.atn.android.PlanAusgabeSubActivity.onCreate(PlanAusgabeSubActivity.java:65)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my program:

```
public void getRoute() {

        db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        txtAbfahrt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txZeit);
        txtDauer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txDauer);
        txtRoute = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txUmstieg);
        txtUmstiege = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txRoute);

        db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        // Alle Daten der Datenbank abrufen mithilfe eines Cursors
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT \tstrftime('%H:%M', f.abfahrt) AS Abfahrt,\n" +
                "\tstrftime('%H:%M', f.ankunft) AS Ankunft,\n" +
                "\tstrftime('%H:%M', strftime('%s',f.ankunft)- strftime('%s',f.abfahrt), 'unixepoch') AS Dauer,\n" +
                "\tr.name AS Route,\n" +
                "\tcount(u.fahrt_id) AS Umstiege\n" +
                "FROM \tscotty_fahrt f\n" +
                "JOIN \tscotty_haltestelle start \tON f.start_id \t= start.id\n" +
                "JOIN \tscotty_haltestelle ziel \tON f.ziel_id \t= ziel.id\n" +
                "JOIN \tscotty_route r \t\t\tON f.route_id \t= r.id\n" +
                "LEFT OUTER JOIN        scotty_umstiegsstelle u\t\t ON f.id   = u.fahrt_id\n" +
                "WHERE \tstart.name = 'Linz/Donau Hbf (Busterminal)'\n" +
                "AND \tziel.name = 'Neufelden Busterminal (Schulzentrum)'\n" +
                "GROUP BY u.fahrt_id",null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            //in this string we get the record for each row from the column "name"
            int i =0;
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutausgabe,null);
            View insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.layout);

            String abfahrtszeit = cursor.getString(0);
            String dauer = cursor.getString(1);
            String route = cursor.getString(2);
            String umstiege = cursor.getString(3);

            ((ViewGroup) insertPoint).addView(v, i, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            txtAbfahrt.setText(abfahrtszeit);
            txtDauer.setText(dauer);
            txtRoute.setText(route);
            txtUmstiege.setText(umstiege);
            i++;
        }

        //here we close the cursor because we do not longer need it
        //}
        cursor.close();
        myDbHelper.close();
    }
```

Comment: Post `layoutausgabe.xml`

Comment: which is line number 111 in PlanAusgabeSubActivity

Comment: please can u tell me which line give nullpointer exception

Comment: I think your `cursor is null`. Put null check before using cursor.

Comment: the cursor is not null

Comment: line 111 is txtAbfahrt.setText(abfahrtszeit);

Comment: then `txtAbfahrt` will be null. So, you should inflate layout before finding the views which reside in the layout

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
inflater.findViewById(R.id.txZeit);
```

istead of this

```
findViewById(R.id.txZeit);
```

Comment: we use View instance to use "findViewById()", not the LayoutInflater instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not inflate your layout. Please inflate like :

```
 view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_layout, null, false);
```

and then access your Component in refrence with this

```
    txtAbfahrt = (TextView)view .findViewById(R.id.txZeit);
    txtDauer = (TextView)view .findViewById(R.id.txDauer);
    txtRoute = (TextView)view .findViewById(R.id.txUmstieg);
    txtUmstiege = (TextView)view .findViewById(R.id.txRoute);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you TextViews txtAbfahrt, txtDauer, txtRoute and txtUmstiege are contained in your layoutausgabe.

You need find them after you inflate layoutausgabe. And you need to find them in `v` variable.

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    //in this string we get the record for each row from the column "name"
    int i =0;
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutausgabe,null);
    View insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.layout);

    String abfahrtszeit = cursor.getString(0);
    String dauer = cursor.getString(1);
    String route = cursor.getString(2);
    String umstiege = cursor.getString(3);

    txtAbfahrt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txZeit);
    txtDauer = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txDauer);
    txtRoute = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txUmstieg);
    txtUmstiege = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txRoute);

    ((ViewGroup) insertPoint).addView(v, i, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    txtAbfahrt.setText(abfahrtszeit);
    txtDauer.setText(dauer);
    txtRoute.setText(route);
    txtUmstiege.setText(umstiege);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
// some code here
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutausgabe,null);
// then find view by its id


}
```

First inflate the layout, then find the associated views